# Can class object be called from React Component Prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I'm studying ReactNative.Navigator.renderScene props.

```
'use strict';
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import ReactNative from 'react-native';
const {
  TouchableHighlight,
  Navigator,
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  View,

} = ReactNative;

class TestClass extends Component{
  render(){
    return <Text>test</Text>
  }
}
class MyTag extends Component{
  render(){
    return <Text>test</Text>
  }
}
class Main extends Component{
  render(){
    const routes =[{component:TestClass,index:0},{component:MyTag,index:1}]
    return(
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={routes[0]}
        initialRouteStack={routes}
        renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
          <View><TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
            if (route.index === 0) {
            navigator.push(routes[1]);
          } else {
            navigator.pop();
          }
          }}><View>{route.component}</View>
      </TouchableHighlight></View>
        }
      />

    )
 }

}



AppRegistry.registerComponent('ChoiceComponent', () => Main);
```

**Can component  in routes variable be called by using {route.component}  in renderScene props in JSX**?

TestClass is called correctly if {route.component} is changed into <Test Class />.

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking if you can use an object property (`route.component`) in place of a class name. Absolutely! Remember, these are just identifiers. You use it exactly the same way you used the class name.

So instead of

```
{route.component}
```

you want

```
<route.component />
```

(**But** keep reading, we may have to do more.)

Example:

```js
class Example1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div style={{color: "blue"}}>{this.props.text}</div>;
  }
}
class Example2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div style={{color: "green"}}>{this.props.text}</div>;
  }
}
const routes = [
  {component: Example1},
  {component: Example2}
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>{routes.map(route => <route.component text="Hi there" />)}</div>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

The above works, but as far as I can tell from [the React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized), our component identifier name should start with a capital letter:

> **User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized**
>
> When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a built-in component like `<div>` or `<span>` and results in a string `'div'` or `'span'` passed to `React.createElement`. Types that start with a capital letter like `<Foo />` compile to `React.createElement(Foo)` and correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.

In our case, it's `route.component`, which is currently handled correctly (because of the `.`; it wouldn't if it were `route_component`, for instance), but that appears to be undocumented behavior. (Supporting the `.` is documented behavior, what appears undocumented is allowing you to start with a lower-case letter when it's not a simple identifier.)

So I think to be officially in line with the docs, we'd want to assign that to a capitalized identifier:

```
const RouteComponent = route.component;
return <RouteComponent text="Hi there" />;
```

Like so:

```js
class Example1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div style={{color: "blue"}}>{this.props.text}</div>;
  }
}
class Example2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div style={{color: "green"}}>{this.props.text}</div>;
  }
}
const routes = [
  {component: Example1},
  {component: Example2}
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>{routes.map(route => {
    const RouteComponent = route.component;
    return <RouteComponent text="Hi there" />;
  })}</div>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It worked!!!
I reread React official document,and I found javascript objects enclosed in {} are text or function, and not used in my way.

I will use capitalized identifier from now on as you say.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @user2255716: Glad that helped. I'm not sure what you mean about *"I found javascript objects enclosed in {} are text or function, and not used in my way."* The expression can result in anything, and it *is* used...